# What is the function of gpgkeys_finger.exe, gpgkeys_ldap.exe

Tags: gnupg

I downloaded GnuPG 1.4.19. Among the executable, there are

- `gpgkeys_hkp.exe`,
- `gpgkeys_finger.exe` and
- `gpgkeys_ldap.exe`.

I found that the first of the three executable is necessary for communication with the public key servers. What is the function of

- `gpgkeys_finger.exe` and
- `gpgkeys_ldap.exe`?

Comment: Logically one would think based on the file name and knowing GPG functionality in general these would be related to FINGERPRINT and LDAP related functionality so perhaps with certs, keyserver operations, etc. I don't have an answer so just leaving this as a comment, I'm surprised the installation guide wouldn't have something about these executable files though as I'd base the most accuate answer off what the source/developers/vendors of the sofware provides if ever possible rather than someone else's word on such matters.

Comment: Another thing you could do if you want to find out is maybe install it on a dummy test system, and then see if the EXE open from command line and has any help detail with a help switch, etc.  Just some quick ideas I can think of that I'd try in a test environment perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

These are key server protocol drivers, with other words they implement different ways to access key servers with GnuPG. In the case of the listed ones, HKP is the protocol commonly used today. The finger protocol probably had more wide-spread use as resource lookup schema in companies earlier but is still available, today companies usuallly will use LDAP databases for both storing user information and also verifying credentials.

These applications are not meant to be executed manually, there is no documentation on how to use them. As I was catched interest on my own, I replaced `gpgkeys_hkp` with a small wrapper script (for Linux systems, on Windows you'd need another one) intercepting the input to the actual binary:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

tee /tmp/gpgkeys_hkp.log | /usr/lib/gnupg/gpgkeys_hkp_
```

`tee` dumps everything on STDIN to `/tmp/gpgkeys_hkp.log`, and then forwards the same input to the renamed, actual `gpgkeys_hkp` implementation. Searching for a key `email@jenserat.de` reveals following commands sent to the key server driver for searching

```
# This is a GnuPG 1.4.19 keyserver communications file
VERSION 1
PROGRAM 1.4.19
SCHEME hkp
HOST pool.sks-keyservers.net
PATH /
COMMAND SEARCH

email@jenserat.de
```

and finally fetching the key

```
# This is a GnuPG 1.4.19 keyserver communications file
VERSION 1
PROGRAM 1.4.19
SCHEME hkp
HOST pool.sks-keyservers.net
PATH /
COMMAND GET

0x0D69E11F12BDBA077B3726AB4E1F799AA4FF2279
```

When trying to run those on Windows you *might* get in trouble because of different encoding of line endings (`CRLF`/`\r\n` in Windows instead of `LF`/`\n` in Linux), but saving those contents as "UNIX"-encoded text files and finally reading from those files should work fine and reveal the results:

```
gpgkeys_hkp <input.txt     # on Linux/other unixoid systems
gpgkeys_hkp.exe <input.txt # for Windows
```